# Java BiFunction to manipulate data over an iteration

Tags: java, collections, functional-programming, functional-interface

I'm writing a Java code that looks like this, and I have the feel it could be improved with some functional programming stuff :)

```
int rank = 1;

for (int i = 0; i < activities.size(); i++) {
    if (i == 0) {
        activities.get(i).setRank(rank);
    else {
        float currentAverage = activities.get(i).getQualityAverage();
        float previousAverage = activities.get(i - 1).getQualityAverage();

        activities.get(i).setRank(currentAverage == previousAverage ? rank : ++rank);
    }
}
```

Assuming that activities List is sorted, the sense of this code is to assign a rank (a score) to every activity according with its place in the list. But there's a rule in the `else` case (when the itteration is equal or higher than second element) where I'm using the rank assigned to the previous element if both elements' `qualityAverage` property is exactly the same.

For instance:

| Activity | Quality Average | Rank |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Read | 10 | 1 |
| Workout | 9.5 | 2 |
| Write | 9.2 | 3 |
| Study | 9.2 | 3 |
| Clean | 8 | 4 |
| Play guitar | 8 | 4 |

As I mentioned at the beginning, how could I write a Java BiFunction (maybe something similar to `reduce()`) in order to achieve a cleaner and smarter code.

Comment: *I have the feel it could be improved with some functional programming...* I highly doubt it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can improve your code a little by writing it like this

```
int rank = 1;
activities.get(0).setRank(rank);
for (int i = 1; i < activities.size(); i++) {
  float previousAverage = activities.get(i - 1).getQualityAverage();
  float currentAverage = activities.get(i).getQualityAverage();
  activities.get(i).setRank(currentAverage == previousAverage ? rank : ++rank);
}
```

It will be the clearest way to demonstrate your logic. For BiFunction you don't have enough variables. You can use a Consumer in your logic but in my opinion in this case it would be an over-engineering

p.s. and also can't compare correctly two float values by using `currentAverage == previousAverage` in some cases it return false negative answer

Comment: I think, it’s even more readable when using `if(currentAverage != previousAverage) { rank++; } activities.get(i).setRank(rank);` You may also put `float previousAverage = activities.get(0).getQualityAverage();` before the loop and do `previousAverage = currentAverage;` as the last statement of the loop body.

Comment: Thanks for improving my code. The main idea was to show that clean readable code can be written without using unnecessary processing. And besides, it will work faster in some cases due to the lack of costs for creating a stream, for example

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a stream-based solution, you're not likely to find one that's an improvement, because your logic is stateful and streams are designed for stateless operations. I would just extract the last average to a variable to avoid the repeated lookups:

```
int rank = 0;
float average = -1; // or some other invalid value

for (var activity : activities) {
    activity.setRank(average == activity.getQualityAverage() ? rank : ++rank);
    average = activity.getQualityAverage();
}
```

Comment: “to avoid the repeated lookups” but then, doing `activity.getQualityAverage()` twice, having exactly as many lookups as in the OP’s code…

Comment: I meant list lookups. You could do `average == (average = activity.getQualityAverage())` too, but that felt like too much.

Comment: I’d avoid code duplication in general. And for common implementations, the list lookup is on part with calling a getter, performance-wise. Doing the assignment inside the expression is a similar code smell as performing an increment operation inside a conditional expression inside a method invocation argument. I think, another local variable and an explicit `if(currentAverage != average) { rank++; average = currentAverage; }` won’t hurt…

Comment: I agree about the increment, but it was already in the OP's code, and I was trying to trim it down, not make it clunkier.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a static function in your Utility class or any other class, then use java stream to iterate the List. Here is an example:

```
public static void assignRanks(List<Activity> activities) {
    // Create a stream of indices paired with activities (with an initial state)
    Stream.iterate(new Object[] {1, null},  // initial: {rank, previousActivity} 
                  entry -> {
                      int nextRank = entry[0].equals(activities.get((int)entry[1] + 1).getQualityAverage())
                                    ? (int)entry[0] : (int)entry[0] + 1;
                      return new Object[]{ nextRank, (int)entry[1] + 1 };
                  })
          .limit(activities.size()) // Limit the stream to the size of the activities list
          .forEachOrdered(entry -> activities.get((int)entry[1]).setRank((int)entry[0]));
}
```

Comment: You are trying to use a two element array for three different variables: the list index, the rank, and the previous activity value. Your comment, “initial: {rank, previousActivity}” indicates that you initially forgot about the index, then, right in the next expression `entry[0].equals(activities.get((int)entry[1] + 1).getQualityAverage())` you are not only trying to use the “previousActivity” as index but also the rank as previousActivity with `entry[0].equals(…)` which, even if you used the right index, ignores the fact that your initial value is `null` so you can’t invoke `equals` on it.